# How do I add closure to loadRequest?

Tags: ios, swift

My goal is to do an activity indicator whenever the webView is still fetching data from the server

but I can't seem to find a way to do so. The only way I could think of is to a closure but how to do so?

If I don't add any activity indicator, then it would just blank white screen then after a certain period of time then the web page will show up. It is not a good user experience.

Here's the code

```
import UIKit

class SignupWebViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var signupWebView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://www.example.com/merchants/signup")

        // How Do i do a closure here?
        signupWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement `UIWebViewDelegate` methods. Before load the request, do this:

```swift
signupWebView.delegate = self;
```

And don't forget to add this to your ViewController

```swift
class SignupWebViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
```

Then add your logic to this methods:

```swift
optional public func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    // show your activity indicator
}

optional public func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    // hide your activity indicator
}
```

By the way, [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) is deprecated now. Use [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) instead.